# STFT understanding using librosa

Tags: python, audio, fft, sampling, librosa

I  have an audio sample of about 14 seconds in 8khz Sample Rate.
Im using librosa to extract some features from this audio file.

```
y, sr = librosa.load(file_name)
stft = np.abs(librosa.stft(y, n_fft=n_fft))

# file_length = 14.650022675736961 #sec
# defaults 
# n_fft =2048
# hop_length = 512 # win_length/4 = n_fft/4 = 512 (win_length = n_fft default)

#windowsTime = n_fft * Ts # (1/sr)

stft.shape
# (1025, 631)
```

Specshow :

```
librosa.display.specshow(stft, x_axis='time', y_axis='log')
```

[![stft sr = 22050][1]][1]

Now, 
i can understand the shape of the STFT

```
631 time bins = are 4 * ( file_length / Ts * windowsTime) #overlapping
1025 frequency bins = Frames frequency gap sr/n_fft.
so there are 1025 frequencies in 0 to sr/2(Nyquest)
```

what i cant understand is the different plot of two different sample rates
with same ratios.
1 - 22050 as librosa default
2 - 8khz as sampling rate file

```
y2, sr = librosa.load(file_name, sr=None)

n_fft2 =743 # (same ratio to get same visuals for comparsion)
hop_length = 186 # (1/4 n_fft by default)

stft2 = np.abs(librosa.stft(y2, n_fft=n_fft2))
```

so ofc the shappe of stft will be different

```
stft2.shape
# (372, 634)
```

[![stft sr = 743][2]][2]

**1. but why is the absoulte frequencies are not the same? its the same signal just not being oversampled so each sample is unique.
what am i missing? is it the static y axis?**

**2. i couldnt understand the time bins values. im expecting bins in the number of frames when the first 1  is in the hop length and the second bin is windowTime from that point until the end of the file. but the units are wierd?**

i want to be able to extract the magnitude of a specific Fbin in a specific time (frame) or additionally be able to sum some of those to get the magnitue for time RANGE.

Therefore, if  i take stft[number of fBin] which is 1 row of 1025 fBins (stft[1025]) and look at it contents so stft[0] contains 630 points, which are exactly 630 time points for each frequency so each of the frames 1-1025 will have the same time points.

so if i take one sample which suits all the other fbins as well ( same time points) which is stft[0]
i would be able to choose time frame and fBin and get the spcific magnitude:

```
times =  librosa.core.frames_to_time(stft2[0], sr=sr2, n_fft=n_fft2, hop_length=hop_length) 

fft_bin = 6
time_idx = 10

print('freq (Hz)', freqs[fft_bin])
print('time (s)', times[time_idx])
print('amplitude', stft[fft_bin, time_idx])
```

array([0.047375, 0.047625, 0.04825 , 0.04825 , 0.046875, 0.04675 ,
       0.05    , 0.051625, 0.051   , 0.048   , 0.05225 , 0.050375,
       0.04925 , 0.04725 , 0.051625, 0.0465  , 0.05225 , 0.05    ,
       0.053   , 0.053875, 0.048   , 0.0485  , 0.047875, 0.04775 ,
       0.0485  , 0.049   , 0.051375, 0.047125, 0.051125, 0.047125,
       0.04725 , 0.05025 , 0.05425 , 0.05475 , 0.051375, 0.060375,
       0.050625, 0.04875 , 0.054125, 0.048   , 0.05025 , 0.052375,
       0.04975 , 0.054125, 0.055625, 0.047125, 0.0475  , 0.047   ,
       0.049875, 0.05025 , 0.048375, 0.047   , 0.050625, 0.05    ,
       0.046625, 0.04925 , 0.048   , 0.049125, 0.05375 , 0.0545  ,
       0.04925 , 0.049125, 0.049125, 0.049625, 0.047   , 0.047625,
       0.0535  , 0.051875, 0.05075 , 0.04975 , 0.047375, 0.049   ,
       0.0485  , 0.050125, 0.048   , 0.05475 , 0.05175 , 0.050125,
       0.04725 , 0.0575  , 0.056875, 0.047   , 0.0485  , 0.055375,
       0.04975 , 0.047   , 0.0495  , 0.051375, 0.04675 , 0.04925 ,
       0.052125, 0.04825 , 0.048125, 0.046875, 0.047   , 0.048625,
       0.050875, 0.05125 , 0.04825 , 0.052125, 0.052375, 0.05125 ,
       0.049875, 0.048625, 0.04825 , 0.0475  , 0.048375, 0.050875,
       0.052875, 0.0475  , 0.0485  , 0.05225 , 0.053625, 0.05075 ,
       0.0525  , 0.047125, 0.0485  , 0.048875, 0.049   , 0.0515  ,
       0.055875, 0.0515  , 0.05025 , 0.05125 , 0.054625, 0.05525 ,
       0.047   , 0.0545  , 0.052375, 0.049875, 0.051   , 0.048625,
       0.0475  , 0.048   , 0.048875, 0.050625, 0.05375 , 0.051875,
       0.048125, 0.052125, 0.048125, 0.051   , 0.052625, 0.048375,
       0.047625, 0.05    , 0.048125, 0.050375, 0.049125, 0.053125,
       0.053875, 0.05075 , 0.052375, 0.048875, 0.05325 , 0.05825 ,
       0.055625, 0.0465  , 0.05475 , 0.051125, 0.048375, 0.0505  ,
       0.04675 , 0.0495  , 0.04725 , 0.046625, 0.049625, 0.054   ,
       0.056125, 0.05175 , 0.050625, 0.050375, 0.047875, 0.047   ,
       0.048125, 0.048875, 0.050625, 0.049875, 0.047   , 0.0505  ,
       0.047   , 0.053125, 0.047625, 0.05025 , 0.04825 , 0.05275 ,
       0.051625, 0.05    , 0.051625, 0.05425 , 0.052   , 0.04775 ,
       0.047   , 0.049125, 0.05375 , 0.0535  , 0.04925 , 0.05125 ,
       0.046375, 0.04775 , 0.04775 , 0.0465  , 0.047   , 0.04675 ,
       0.04675 , 0.04925 , 0.05125 , 0.046375, 0.04825 , 0.0525  ,
       0.057875, 0.056375, 0.054375, 0.04825 , 0.0535  , 0.05475 ,
       0.0485  , 0.048875, 0.048625, 0.0485  , 0.047625, 0.046875,
       0.0465  , 0.05125 , 0.054   , 0.05    , 0.048   , 0.047875,
       0.0515  , 0.048125, 0.055875, 0.054875, 0.051625, 0.048125,
       0.047625, 0.048375, 0.052875, 0.0485  , 0.0475  , 0.0495  ,
       0.05025 , 0.05675 , 0.0585  , 0.051625, 0.05625 , 0.0605  ,
       0.052125, 0.0495  , 0.049   , 0.047875, 0.051375, 0.054125,
       0.0525  , 0.0515  , 0.057875, 0.055   , 0.05375 , 0.046375,
       0.04775 , 0.0485  , 0.050125, 0.050875, 0.04925 , 0.049125,
       0.0465  , 0.04975 , 0.053375, 0.05225 , 0.0475  , 0.046375,
       0.05375 , 0.049875, 0.049875, 0.047375, 0.049125, 0.049375,
       0.04875 , 0.048125, 0.05075 , 0.0505  , 0.046375, 0.047375,
       0.048625, 0.0485  , 0.047125, 0.052625, 0.051125, 0.04725 ,
       0.050875, 0.053875, 0.0475  , 0.0495  , 0.051   , 0.055   ,
       0.053   , 0.050125, 0.04675 , 0.05375 , 0.054375, 0.04725 ,
       0.046875, 0.04925 , 0.04725 , 0.0495  , 0.05075 , 0.050875,
       0.04775 , 0.05125 , 0.050125, 0.047875, 0.04825 , 0.046625,
       0.0475  , 0.046375, 0.04775 , 0.05075 , 0.048125, 0.046375,
       0.049625, 0.0495  , 0.04675 , 0.046625, 0.0475  , 0.04825 ,
       0.053   , 0.050875, 0.049   , 0.057875, 0.058875, 0.049875,
       0.049125, 0.0475  , 0.05225 , 0.055   , 0.055375, 0.053875,
       0.051125, 0.049875, 0.05025 , 0.050875, 0.049   , 0.0575  ,
       0.051875, 0.049375, 0.04775 , 0.051125, 0.050375, 0.0465  ,
       0.047375, 0.0465  , 0.046375, 0.048875, 0.051875, 0.047   ,
       0.047125, 0.047125, 0.046875, 0.049625, 0.048625, 0.051   ,
       0.049   , 0.046375, 0.049   , 0.056125, 0.054625, 0.047625,
       0.046625, 0.0475  , 0.051875, 0.05175 , 0.047625, 0.050375,
       0.055125, 0.05275 , 0.047125, 0.05325 , 0.060125, 0.056625,
       0.053   , 0.052125, 0.047125, 0.04825 , 0.050375, 0.05025 ,
       0.048   , 0.046625, 0.047125, 0.04875 , 0.047   , 0.05525 ,
       0.0535  , 0.047   , 0.0495  , 0.0535  , 0.05125 , 0.046625,
       0.0495  , 0.04675 , 0.04875 , 0.047125, 0.04975 , 0.047   ,
       0.049875, 0.046875, 0.047125, 0.048   , 0.046375, 0.0495  ,
       0.04975 , 0.05125 , 0.048375, 0.049125, 0.0515  , 0.048375,
       0.052375, 0.051125, 0.046375, 0.047125, 0.050375, 0.0465  ,
       0.052375, 0.05375 , 0.04925 , 0.05025 , 0.0565  , 0.054875,
       0.048   , 0.049375, 0.052625, 0.055375, 0.053375, 0.05075 ,
       0.048875, 0.05475 , 0.05075 , 0.0485  , 0.049125, 0.0475  ,
       0.047375, 0.047375, 0.047   , 0.052125, 0.053875, 0.049   ,
       0.052625, 0.0485  , 0.04675 , 0.04875 , 0.05    , 0.0545  ,
       0.05025 , 0.0495  , 0.0515  , 0.0485  , 0.05025 , 0.0465  ,
       0.0465  , 0.048375, 0.06375 , 0.10175 , 0.11975 , 0.118375,
       0.121375, 0.12675 , 0.123   , 0.095375, 0.055   , 0.05525 ,
       0.04775 , 0.053125, 0.052375, 0.056625, 0.0565  , 0.046875,
       0.048   , 0.05175 , 0.048   , 0.052   , 0.048   , 0.048   ,
       0.05175 , 0.05025 , 0.049625, 0.049625, 0.047375, 0.046625,
       0.052375, 0.0555  , 0.051375, 0.050625, 0.052375, 0.050125,
       0.048   , 0.052125, 0.052125, 0.0495  , 0.048875, 0.048   ,
       0.049875, 0.051125, 0.050625, 0.048   , 0.0465  , 0.048   ,
       0.04675 , 0.050875, 0.048   , 0.046625, 0.0495  , 0.050375,
       0.046625, 0.0515  , 0.049875, 0.049625, 0.04675 , 0.049125,
       0.05025 , 0.050375, 0.04725 , 0.047625, 0.047   , 0.051625,
       0.0485  , 0.05225 , 0.046875, 0.0475  , 0.04825 , 0.050375,
       0.05725 , 0.052375, 0.048   , 0.046375, 0.0475  , 0.0495  ,
       0.047875, 0.046375, 0.049875, 0.046875, 0.048   , 0.046875,
       0.048625, 0.047125, 0.046625, 0.05    , 0.048875, 0.04675 ,
       0.050125, 0.05425 , 0.051375, 0.050125, 0.053375, 0.052   ,
       0.053875, 0.048   , 0.05575 , 0.049875, 0.052125, 0.048875,
       0.047375, 0.048875, 0.049125, 0.047375, 0.047375, 0.047625,
       0.0495  , 0.04825 , 0.047875, 0.04875 , 0.054   , 0.052125,
       0.051   , 0.046625, 0.04925 , 0.05075 , 0.054375, 0.0555  ,
       0.051625, 0.046625, 0.052125, 0.055875, 0.047   , 0.053875,
       0.050875, 0.0505  , 0.0465  , 0.053125, 0.050875, 0.050625,
       0.051125, 0.050875, 0.056875, 0.04925 , 0.050625, 0.054125,
       0.056625, 0.05025 , 0.0465  , 0.04675 , 0.049625, 0.047   ,
       0.048375, 0.047125, 0.04875 , 0.048375, 0.048875, 0.04775 ,
       0.04775 , 0.047   , 0.052125, 0.050875, 0.054   , 0.058375,
       0.054   , 0.049125, 0.04675 , 0.051875, 0.05425 , 0.050125,
       0.04675 , 0.047625, 0.046375, 0.05275 , 0.053   , 0.04875 ,
       0.049125, 0.047125, 0.049375, 0.0475  , 0.051125, 0.0495  ,
       0.052375, 0.047   , 0.047125, 0.050875])

```
  [1]: https://i.imgur.com/OeKzvrb.png
  [2]: https://i.imgur.com/ALtba5F.png
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying `sr` as parameter to `specshow`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 1:

You need to specify the sampling rate when using `specshow`:

```
librosa.display.specshow(stft, x_axis='time', y_axis='log', sr=sr)
```

Otherwise the default value (22,050 Hz) will be used (see [docs](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.display.specshow.html)).

Question 2:

`librosa.core.frames_to_time` does not take `stft[0]` as argument, which would be the frequency bins of the first frame. Instead, it takes *number of frames* as first argument.

Imagine you have an audio signal with `sr=10000` Hz. Then you run an STFT over it using `n_fft=2000` and `hop_length=1000`. Then you get one *frame* per hop and the hop is 0.1s long, because 10000 samples correspond to 1s and 1000 samples (1 hop) therefore correspond to 0.1s.

`stft[0]` is *not* a frame number. Instead the first `stft` is of shape `(1 + n_fft/2, t)` (see [here](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.core.stft.html)). This means the first dimension is the frequency bin and the second dimension is the frame number (`t`).

The total number of frames in `stft` is therefore `stft.shape[1]`.
To get the length of the source audio, you could do:

```
time = librosa.core.frames_to_time(stft.shape[1], sr=sr, hop_length=hop_length, n_fft=n_fft)
```

Comment: one of the biggest facepalms i ever had. Can you please Asnwer the second question aswell? Thanks!

Comment: Cant close because 2nd Questions sitll havent answered.  Thanks again.

Comment: How about now? All questions answered?

Comment: i understood what you said. but i think i miss leaded the question. i did edit the post to be clearer. thank you very much for the effort, please have a look again? :)

Comment: i think i got what i needed when doing: ```times = librosa.core.frames_to_time(range(0, stft.shape[1]), sr=sr, n_fft=n_fft, hop_length=hop_length) 
```

Comment: Hm. Somehow the formatting of your question is now defunct. Also, admittedly, I'm not sure I fully understand what your question is beyond what I answered.