# How can I reconstruct the STFT matrix from a mel spectrogram in librosa so I reconstruct the original audio?

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, spectrogram, librosa

I have generated a melspectrogram in librosa using the following code

```
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import librosa
import librosa.display
import pylab
import numpy as np


x, sr = librosa.load('audio/example.wav')
mel = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(x,sr)
P = librosa.power_to_db(mel, ref=np.max)
librosa.display.specshow(P)
pylab.savefig("example.png", bbox_inches=None, pad_inches=0)
```

As I understand, the spectrogram is simply a visual representation of the STFT matrix for an audio signal. I'm trying to reconstruct the STFT matrix used to generate the spectrogram in order to pass it through the griffin lim function. How should I do this?

Generating Spectrogram using STFT data

```
def generate_spectrogram(x, sr):
    X = librosa.stft(x)
    Xdb = librosa.amplitude_to_db(abs(X))
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10), dpi=100, frameon=False)
    ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1], frameon=False)
    ax.axis('off')
    librosa.display.specshow(Xdb, sr=sr, cmap='gray', x_axis='time', y_axis='hz')
    plt.savefig('example.png', quality=100, bbox_inches=0, pad_inches=0)
    librosa.cache.clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this question is suitable in its current form in this forum (stack exchange might perhaps be a better fit), but as it is quite relevant for DNN based speech synthesis pipelines, I think it is a good idea to expand on it a bit.

We cannot reconstruct exactly the STFT from a Mel spectrogram. The reason is that we the Mel is a 'compressed' version of the STFT with the frequencies coming from the Mel scale and then applying (to the STFT) triangular filters at these frequencies. Generally, we lose information going from STFT to mel. See this excellent article for detailed explanation.

https://haythamfayek.com/2016/04/21/speech-processing-for-machine-learning.html

Now, to get back to your question - I assume that you are working on speech synthesis in the manner of the Tacotron [1] work - in order to apply Griffin Lim, as you correctly note, we need the linear spectrogram. The way it is done in the paper is to use a neural network to transform Mel to STFT. They call this a postnet, as it serves as a post processor after the Mels are predicted.

To set up this network, convert ground truth (target) audio into Mels, and create a recurrent network (CBHG or anything else) to transform it into STFT equivalents. Minimize loss between these STFT predictions and the actual STFT which we can create from target audio.

[1] https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.10135

Comment: I am using spectrograms for audio style transfer using cyclegans actually. I'm not sure if the process you described above for converting Mel to STFT is the same. What if I construct a regular spectrogram from the STFT matrix, as opposed to using librosa's built in melspectrogram function? Would I be able to pull the STFT matrix out of this spectrogram since it was generated from the librosa.stft function?

Comment: Not sure I get context (seems like you're trying to get STFT, but are starting with Mels). In librosa, you can directly get the STFT with librosa.stft, and use that on Griffin Lim later. You're already doing that in generate_spectrogram(). https://librosa.org/doc/latest/generated/librosa.stft.html#librosa.stft and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57058875/stft-understanding-using-librosa

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do sorry if I wasn't clear. I want to be able to go from a generated spectrogram (in png form) back into the STFT matrix. I'm passing in the spectrograms to a cyclegans for style transfer, and want to reconstruct the audio once the spectrogram been modified. Since I've constructed the spectrogram using STFT data, I am looking for a way to reverse that process and retrieve the STFT in order to reconstruct the audio from the modified image.

Comment: It should be possible to revert audio from the STFT (which here would be the output of the CycleGAN) using the Griffin Lim procedure. There are several places on the net where one could get an implementation. Note though that a spectrogram is not a 'png'. The image is a visual representation of the spectral energy, but we have to store it in the disc as numpy arrays. If you store it as an image, to get back the spectrograms, we have to apply appropriate scaling factors. Example Griffin Lim implementation: https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/25002923